# Definition of Frobenius automorphism

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, automorphism-group, galois-extensions

I quote the following problem from the chapter Hilbert's Ramification Theory of Jurgen Neukirch

> Let $L/K$ is a Galois extension with prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}$, unramified over $K$, then there is one and only one automorphism $\Phi_{\mathfrak{P}}\in\operatorname{Gal}L/K$, s.t. $\Phi_{\mathfrak{P}}(a)\equiv a^q \pmod{\mathfrak{P}}$, where $q$ is the size of the residue field $O_K/\mathfrak{P}\cap O_K$. It is called the Frobenius Automorphism.

Now, if we take $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $p=\mathfrak{P}\cap \mathbb{Z}$, I know that the residue field $O_L/\mathfrak{P}$ is a finite extension over $\mathbb{F}_p$,  so, $a\mapsto a^p$ is a frobenius automorphism in $O_L/\mathfrak{P}$ and it generates all the other frobenius automorphisms. But the definition of the automorphism from the exercise seems different. Am I missing anything? How can it be a frobenius automorphism? The frobenius automorphism in the sense of finite field is not matching with this.

Comment: $K$ is a number field, $a\in O_L$ and $q$ is the cardinality of $O_K/(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_K)$. If $K=\Bbb{Q}$ then $O_K=\Bbb{Z}$ and $q=p$ is the characteristic of the residue fields.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it should have been $K=\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$. Why $q=p$ in this case because according to neukirch $q$ is $O_L/\mathfrak{P}:\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, not the characteristic. I have updated the question mentioning these clearly. Sorry for my earlier mistakes..

Comment: The number $q$ is *not* necessarily equal to $p$.  The label "Frobenius" does not have a single never-changing meaning. It depends on *context*.  For example, if $\mathbf F_{q^n}/\mathbf F_{q}$ is an extension of finite fields where the base field has order $q$, then its Galois group is generated by $x \mapsto x^q$ on $\mathbf F_{q^n}$, and in this setting of finite fields we call the $q$th power mapping the "Frobenius map".  The Frobenius automorphism in the sense of number fields matches *this* meaning of Frobenius on finite fields. Everything makes sense in the right context.

Comment: @KCd thanks for replying. I have edited the question. Can you please point out how the two definition of Frobenius is matching?

Comment: Your quote from Neukrich has a bad typo: $q$ is *not* the degree $[\mathcal O_L/\mathfrak P : \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z]$. In the body of your question, don't write "$q = [\mathcal O_L/\mathfrak P : \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z]$" either. Your initial mistake that "Frobenius" can only be allowed to be a name for the $p$th power map is leading you to write a strange question. Once you have everything defined correctly (in particular, $q$ is always presented as the size of the residue field at the prime in $\mathcal O_K$ below $\mathfrak P$, and don't confuse size and field degree) then I'll say more.

Comment: In Neukirch it is given as "$q=[k(\mathfrak{P}):k(p)]$" where $k(\mathfrak{P})=O/\mathfrak{P}$ and $k(p)=o/p$, $O,o$ are the integral closure of the corresponding fields. Is it wrong?

Comment: I edited the question as you said @KCd

Comment: When Neukirch writes "$p$", it is not a prime number down in $\mathbf Z$ but the prime below $\mathfrak P$ in $o$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a number field $L$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}\subset O_L$ and $L/K$ Galois. There is some automorphism $\in Gal(L/K)$ whose reduction is the Frobenius. If the extension is unramified at $\mathfrak{P}$ then it is unique and we can call it *the Frobenius*.

It is not true that $q$ is the degree of the extension. It is the cardinality of $O_K/(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_K)$, which is also $p^f$ where $f=[O_K/(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_K):\Bbb{F}_p]$ and $p$ is the characteristic. The order of the Frobenius (here I assume the extension is unramified at $\mathfrak{P}$) is $[O_L/\mathfrak{P}:O_K/(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_K)]$.

Comment: What does "there is one and only one automorphism $\Phi_{\mathfrak{P}}\in\operatorname{Gal}L/K$, s.t. $\Phi_{\mathfrak{P}}(a)\equiv a^q \pmod{\mathfrak{P}}$" means?

Comment: $\forall a\in O_L, \Phi_{\mathfrak{P}}(a)-a^q\in \mathfrak{P}$ where $b\to b^q$ is the Frobenius automorphism of the extension of finite fields $(O_L/\mathfrak{P})/(O_K/(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_K))$

Comment: Doesn't $b\mapsto b^q$ fixes the finite field extension, because $q=p^n$ is the size of the extension field?

Comment: $q$ is the size of $O_K/(\mathfrak{P}\cap O_K)$ so $b\to b^q$ fixes its elements but not those of $O_L/\mathfrak{P}$ (when the latter is larger ie. in the unramified case when $\mathfrak{P}\cap O_K$ doesn't split completely in $O_L$)

Comment: Okay, so this was a typo of Neukirch to define q as the degree of extension..I get it and I will edit the question mentioning this